# Exchange meaning of : and \colon

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, math-operators

I usually use the colon symbol `:` to denote maps. For set syntax there is the `braket` package. So as the spacing of `:` is not appropriate, I want it to behave like `\colon`. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}

\def\textcolon{:} \catcode`\:=\active \def:{\relax\ifmmode\colon\else\textcolon\fi}

\begin{document}

    Here is an example:
    \begin{gather*}
        f: x \mapsto x^2\\
        g\colon \mathds R_+ \ni x \mapsto x^x \in \mathds R\\
        A := \Set{ x \in \mathds R_+ | g(x) < x }
    \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

But that throws the error

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping
>   levels=255].

Without the active definition, it looks like

[image]

Notice that I use `:=` for definitions. That should still be possible. The problem there is that `\colon=` looks terrible:

[image]

---

As I agree with egreg, that using all the active math chars is not a good idea. I'm going with David's approach and use:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}}
\def\colon{\mathrel{:}}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\def\textcoloneq{≔} \newunicodechar{≔}{\ifmmode \mathrel{{\vcentcolon}{=}} \else \textcoloneq \fi}
\def\texteqcolon{≕} \newunicodechar{≕}{\ifmmode \mathrel{{=}{\vcentcolon}} \else \texteqcolon \fi}
```

I use `\AtBeginDocument` so that I can use it together with `fontspec`.

Comment: Don't use `:=` for definitions as it does not vertically center the colon (notice that the dots of colon and the bars of the equal are not symmetric) Use `\coloneqq` from `mathtools` package or `colonequals` from the `colonequals` package.

Comment: @Aditya: That's what `\mathtoolsset{centercolon}` is for!

Comment: Oops, you are right. I did not notice that.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-typeset-correctly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should just need

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}
```

to define `:` to be like `\colon`. the original definitions are:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\colon}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}
```

Comment: You are right, for the normal case this is a good solution. But then `:=` has some space in between. (like `\colon=`, see my updated question). If there is no better solution I could probably use the unicode char for `:=` instead...

Comment: That's really a separate operator, if building it out of `:` and `=` best to do `\mathrel{{:}{=}}` or rather define a command that does that

Answer (score 8):

I guess it's easier to type `\colon` :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\edef\latexordinarycolon{\mathchar\the\mathcode`: } % keep the ordinary :
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\amsmathcolon\colon                             % keep amsmath's \colon
\patchcmd\amsmathcolon{:}{\latexordinarycolon}{}{}  % avoid the mention of : in it
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`:=\active \global\let\mathtools@colon=:    % : is math active with mathtools "centercolon"
\gdef:{\@ifnextchar={\mathtools@colon\mkern-1.2mu}\amsmathcolon}  % if : is followed by = ...
\endgroup
\let\colon\latexordinarycolon                       % Now \colon is a relation symbol

%%% Now we redefine = so that =: works
\edef\latexequal{\mathchar\the\mathcode`= }
\begingroup
\catcode`==\active
\gdef={\latexequal\@ifnextchar:{\afterassignment\mathtools@colon\let\next}{}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`=="8000 }


\begin{document}

Here is an example:
\begin{gather*}
f: x \mapsto x^2\\
g\colon \mathds R_+ \ni x \mapsto x^x \in \mathds R\\
A := \Set{ x \in \mathds R_+ | g(x) < x }\\
a:=b=:c=d
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

As one can see, there's no hope of typing `=:` and get the same as `\eqqcolon`.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately I just noticed that then there are issues with the 'is defined as', `=:`, operator. To make that work `=` would have to be active as well, right?

Comment: @canaaerus Math active. Don't do this: I don't think that using `:` for mappings instead of `\colon` is a big saving. And don't use `:=` or (worse) `=:` (but this is another question: mathematicians have done without them for some centuries and those symbol *don't* convey any meaning that can't be derived from the context).

Comment: It's not about saving in typing, but making the code somewhat readable and editable. Also I must say that there where instances where I did wonder whether an `=` was the initial definition or just a statement of equality; and I was really confused. Especially for local variables that are reused I find it a good practise to hint at definition by `=`. Of course in many cases definition is done not by formula but with some prose, which is still better.

Comment: Why can one see that using `:=` is different from `\coloneqq` ? I could understand your code, as I'm not that well versed in LaTeX, could you please explain a bit, what the differences are ? (Ideally answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264401/is-set-to-colon-but-the-spacing-is-still-wrong-part-2, where essentially this is asked.)

Comment: @user10324 Please, read carefully: `=:` is different from `\eqqcolon`

Comment: @egreg ok, my last comment was unclear (and had an error in it, i meant "couldn't (!) understand your code"), so let me clarify: With "differences" I meant "spacing differences"; of course I can see that the two (in either "orientation" are different, but I didn't understood how your code works, and why, after your  code, in the preamble, `:=` resp. `=:` were different from `\coloneqq` resp. `\eqqcolon` (I updated the graphic my answer to show how both induce different spacing). You said belowthat "one can see that [...]". Unfortunately, I can't really. Could you help me a bit out

Comment: @user10324 No: I can't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: You said in your answer "As one can see, there's no hope of typing =: and get the same as \eqqcolon." Could you explain this sentence please ? I hope I'm not being (too) obnoxious to press you again on this issue.

Comment: @user10324 One should change the meaning of `=` for that, which could possibly have unwanted effects on `\Longrightarrow`.