# Executing a command after a package has been loaded

Tags: fontspec, package-writing

In [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64423/exchange-meaning-of-and-colon) I ended up with

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}
```

But now I'm using the `fontspec` package which redefines `:` with `\AtBeginDocument` itself. So as my own definition comes before `fontspec` is loaded, even putting it in `\AtBeginDocument` won't help.

Is there a way to say “Execute this after `fontspec` has loaded!” or “Execute this at the very end of `\AtBeginDocument`!”?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the documentation of `afterpackage` this should work

```
\usepackage{afterpackage}
\AfterPackage{fontspec}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}}%
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There's also the `scrlfile` package from KOMA-script:

```
\usepackage{scrlfile}
\AfterPackage{fontspec}{%
    \AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}}%
}
```

It has a bunch of other useful commands.

Comment: Actually I do use `scrartcl`. So that clears up why I got “`\AfterPackage` already defined” on `\usepackage{afterpackage}`.

Answer (score 5):

Put it in `\AtBeginDocument` after you load `fontspec` any commands saved by that command are executed in order, so if you do it that way *your* saved commands will be executed after the packages.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I didn't want to do. Actually I'm issuing `\DeclareMathSymbol` in my document class, which I then `\dump` with the rest of the preamble to speed up compilation. `fontspec` can not be dumped, so I put it right before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: ah well an alternative is to patch `\document` to add your hook stuff just after it runs `\@begindocumenthook`