# Why are \colon and \mathpunct{:} not equivalent?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64435/19809), `\colon` is of type `\mathpunct`. But in the MWE below, the outputs of the two lines are not identical. Why not?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & g\colon X\to Y\\
    & g\mathpunct{:} X\to Y
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `amsmath` redefines the `\colon` macro.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `\mathpunct{}` (without `:` inside {}) is the definition of `\colon`. [Link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150573/what-do-empty-math-character-class-symbols-mathpunct-do-and-when-are-the)
2. Both `:` and `\colon` typeset a colon, but `\colon` is a punctuation symbol, while `:` is considered as a relation symbol as regards to spacing. [Link2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas)

Comment: Sorry, but the definition of `\colon` _contains_ `\mathpunct{}`, but is _not equal_ to it. Moreover, this depends on `amsmath` being present.

Comment: This doesn't address the question as `:` is a relation symbol but `\mathpunct{:}` is not.