# `:` is set to `\colon`, but the spacing is still wrong

Tags: math-mode, spacing

This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64423/exchange-meaning-of-and-colon) explains how to make `:` behave as `\colon`. Except that the solution in the most upvoted answer doesn't work 100%. That solution says to make `:` behave in such a way, one has to use the command `\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}`.

With that command it looks like this (how it looks for `\colon` was added as an optical reference):

[image]

So one can see, that the `:`, although it should look like `\colon` actually has the spacing a bit different. **Question 1: Is there a way to fix this ?**

For completeness, this is how it looks, when the above command is disabled, and `:` is displayed as it normally would:

[image]

**Question 2: Does activating this option change in any way the spacing of `:` when it is *not* used in math mode?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a minimal document there is no difference:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}

\begin{document}

\( f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \)

\( f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \)

\end{document}
```

However if you load `amsmath` then the difference you describe does occur:

[image: Ams sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}

\begin{document}

\( f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \)

\( f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \)

\end{document}
```

The reason is that the definition of `\colon` is changed in `amsmath` to

```
\renewcommand{\colon}{\nobreak\mskip2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript
  \mkern-\thinmuskip{:}\mskip6muplus1mu\relax}
```

giving greater spacing.  Thus the simple redefinition of the other answer is not sufficient.  You need to use the more complicated version provided by egreg there instead; his solution loads `mathtools` which loads `amsmath`.

As regards your second question: no, neither of the solutions to the other question affect colons outside of math mode.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation. Before I accept your answer, could you please also answer question 2 ?  And could you please tell me, which version of `:` should be used when defining functions as above for most professional looking documents: The one where Carlisle's redefinition changes `:`, the one with `\colon` or the standard `:` ?

 Also, if you're interested, your answer generated a follow-up question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264401/is-set-to-colon-but-the-spacing-is-still-wrong-part-2, which pertains to `:=`, as egregs answer also has his rough corners.

Comment: I would say the AMS (= American Mathematical Society) definition is the better one for spacing.

Comment: So you mean the use of `\colon` (or a redefinition of `:` that looks like that) is best ? Could you please answer question 2 ?

Comment: 1. Yes - the AMS use this for professional typesseting of their journals.  2. Done.