# `:` is set to `\colon`, but the spacing is still wrong - part 2

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, letterspacing

This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64423/exchange-meaning-of-and-colon) explains how to make `:` behave as `\colon`. It has two solutions. The present question concerns the second, less upvoted solution, egreg solution, as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64423/exchange-meaning-of-and-colon) question of mine, it turned out that the most upvoted solution, Carlisle's solution, is problematic when usd together with `amsmath`. Since I want to use that package, I have to consider egregs solution.

This solution has some rough edges, which is what this question is about: It also pretains to `:=` and `=:` and there is a difference to using `\coloneqq` resp. `\eqqcolon`, as can be seen in

```
\begin{gather*}
a:=b=:c=d\\
a\coloneqq b \eqqcolon c = d
\end{gather*}
```

which displays as

[image]

so the spacing is a bit different, compared to the spacing of the commands in `mathtools` -- look at the red line and at the (barely visible) dotted orange vertical that I draw additionally on top of the screenshot, that make the spacing differences apparent.

**Question 1**: Why is there a difference ?

**Question 2**: In his solution, egreg is somewhat contradictory: After his wizardry, ´:=´ looks like `\coloneqq` (except that the spacing is different, as illustrated above) and also provides an example of this in this MWE - but in the comments he goes on to say, that one shouldn't use `:=`. Why has he then provided it in his MWE ? Should I or should I not use `:=` ? In case both are considered good practice, which one should be used, when one wants to create professional looking documents ?

Comment: See fixed code in my old answer. But I still think that exchanging the meanings of `:` and `\colon` is wrong.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Could you tell me why you think that is wrong ? After all, it would speed up typing (long) texts, as writing `\colon` take more time then a short `:`. BTW, if you could make this comment an answer (and also answer question 2) I'd be very happy to accept it, so that this question is done!

Comment: I'd guess it's wrong because `:` is valid (and common) punctuation. Also, this is more likely to be dupe'd to the other question now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the colon with some “intelligence” in math mode

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\def\ordinarycolon{\mathchar`\:}
\def\colon{\nobreak\mskip2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip\mathord\ordinarycolon\mskip6muplus1mu\relax}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\:\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~}{\new@ifnextchar={\coloneqq\@gobble}{\colon}}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\=\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~}{\new@ifnextchar:{\eqqcolon\@gobble}{\mathrel\mathchar`\=}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\:="8000 \mathcode`\=="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  f : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R} \\
  a := b =: c = d \\
  a \coloneqq b \eqqcolon c = d
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

This shouldn't add different spacings.