# mathtools' \vcentcolon and fourier's utopia

Tags: mathtools, fourier

The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package has a centered colon, `\vcentcolon`, which is used to display the definition symbol `:=` correctly.

However when using the [`fourier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) package, I get the following output

[image]

from

```
$:\vcentcolon=$
```

where I have added a normal colon as comparison.

The second colon is slightly adjusted, but not entirely centered upon the `=`. How do I get `\vcentcolon:` right?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4881/22413).

Comment: It's the first `:` that doesn't look right to me.  Why not write `\vcentcolon\vcentcolon=`?

Comment: The first colon is just for illustration here. I would like `$\vcentcolon=$` to be adjusted correctly.

Comment: @A.Ellett The solutions in the link do the work because they do not use the colon symbol but construct their own dots instead. Thanks for that. I wonder if there is a solution that uses the actual colon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two homegrown possibilities (converted from comments into an answer) in which the colon dots match the height of the equals bars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{stackengine}
% THE FOLLOWING WORKS WHEN fourier PACKAGE IS NOT USED
\newcommand\newvcentcolon{\abovebaseline[.07ex]{\stackanchor[.18ex]{.}{.}}}
%\newcommand\newvcentcolon{\abovebaseline[.02ex]{\stackanchor[.19ex]{.}{.}}}
\newcommand\colonequalA{\mathrel{\newvcentcolon{=}}}

\usepackage{scalerel}
% THE FOLLOWING WORKS WHEN fourier PACKAGE IS NOT USED
%\newcommand\colonequalB{\mathrel{\hstretch{.085}{=}\hspace{.2ex}{=}}}
\newcommand\colonequalB{\mathrel{\hstretch{.13}{=}\hspace{.2ex}{=}}}

\begin{document}

\(x\colonequalA x+1\)

\(x \colonequalB x+1 \)

\end{document}
```

[image]