# Special Symbol "::="

Tags: symbols

As the title says, does LaTeX have this special symbol:

```
::=
```

I tried to look at some cheat-sheets and http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html but could not find it.

Comment: There is also a `\vcentcolon` in the `mathtools` package that has a `:=` symbol with only one colon.  Here is a question related to the question of modifying the look of these symbols: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125023/mathtools-vcentcolon-and-fouriers-utopia

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is called `\Coloneqq` and it's defined by the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, which is an extension of `amsmath`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\Coloneqq
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The package also provides other symbols like the above one (see subsubsection 3.7.3 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf)) including `\vcentcolon` which is a colon properly vertically centered.

Moreover, issuing

```
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}
```

you can have all your math colons (including the `\colon` command) properly vertically centered.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}

\begin{document}
\[
\colon \quad : \quad \coloneqq \quad \Coloneqq
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Package `colonequals` provides such symbols with properly vertically centered colons:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colonequals}

\begin{document}
\[ A \coloncolonequals B \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## OpenType fonts

If the TeX engine supports OpenType fonts (LuaTeX, XeTeX), then the symbol can be used directly as Unicode symbol `⩴` (U+2A74) or macro `\Coloneq`, if package `unicode-math` with a font, which contains this symbol.

When testing fonts, `\tracinglostchars=2` is useful, because then missing characters are also logged on the screen, e.g.:

```
Missing character: There is no ⩴ (U+2A74) in font "[latinmodern-math]:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;"!
```

### Asana-Math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf} 
\begin{document}
  \[ A \Coloneq B \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for Asana-Math]

### XITS Math

\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

> [image: Result for XITS Math]

Answer (score 3):

If you needn't to use any packages, you can define the symbol:

```
\def\cceq{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{::}}{=}}}

$$ A \cceq B $$
\bye
```