# Typesetting displayed equivalences and definitions of unequal length

Tags: typography, lengths

What is the proper way to typeset in LaTeX, in display-mode, a series of equivalences and definitions of unequal lengths of sets ?

Consider for this the following code that I used for a series of equivalences

```
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
y_{0}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1-z^{2}}}{z} & \Longleftrightarrow & y_{0}z=\pm\sqrt{1-z^{2}}\\
 & \Longleftrightarrow & y_{0}^{2}z^{2}=1-z^{2}\\
 & \Longleftrightarrow & (1+y_{0})z^{2}=1\\
 & \Longleftrightarrow & z=\pm\frac{1}{1+y_{0}^{2}}.
\end{array}
$$
```

and the following code I used for definitions of unequal lengths of sets:

```
\begin{alignat*}{1}
D_{1} & :=C_{a}\cap\left\{ (x,y,z)\in D_{2}:x>0\right\} \ \text{and}\\
D_{2} & :=\left\{ (x,y,z)\in D_{1}:x<0\right\} .
\end{alignat*}
```

(Ignore the mathematical non-sense.) 
Are the environments I used as well as their alignments the proper ones for this ?

Comment: First of all: do not use `$$ $$`. Use `\[ \]`.

Comment: To typeset `:=` ("colon-equal", "equal by definition") correctly, see the posting [How to typeset $:=$ correctly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4216/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `align*` environment.

```
\begin{align*}
y_{0}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1-z^{2}}}{z} &\Longleftrightarrow  y_{0}z=\pm\sqrt{1-z^{2}}\\
                                  &\Longleftrightarrow  y_{0}^{2}z^{2}=1-z^{2}\\
                                  &\Longleftrightarrow  (1+y_{0})z^{2}=1\\
                                  &\Longleftrightarrow  z=\pm\frac{1}{1+y_{0}^{2}}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
D_{1} & :=C_{a}\cap\left\{ (x,y,z)\in D_{2}:x>0\right\} \text{ and}\\
D_{2} & :=\left\{ (x,y,z)\in D_{1}:x<0\right\} .
\end{align*}
```

[image]

**ps.** `\left\{ \right\}` is not necessary in your case. Simply use `\{ \}` or some variant `\bigl\{ \bigr\}` or `\Bigl\{ \Bigr\}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please highlight though why it's better to use the `align*` environment over the `array` environment (i.e. why  `align*` is the proper environment in this case) and what the difference to the `alignat*` is ? I compared your and my version and regarding the former, with the `align*` environment everything is display in normal size (where `array` seems to display it in text size), which seems to me to be more a matter of taste than typographical convention and regarding the latter I couldn't see any difference.

Comment: As the name suggests, `array` is to mathematical arrays. In your case, you want to align a set of equations.

Comment: This explanation is only terminological, can you give me an explanation that refers to what these definitions do ? You haven't yet specified why `align*` is better than `alignat*`.

Comment: @user10324 `align*` and `alignat*` are two different (but related) constructions. See http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf

Comment: @daleif Could you be a bit more specific ? I browsed fast through your document, but couldn't find a paragraph that concisely relates to the differences/similarities of these two commands.

Comment: The main difference is when one is using more than one alignment column. Then align adds space between the alignment columns, alignat does not. The later also need you to explicitly specify how many alignment columns there will be. In that document, look at the images. Not everything is explained in words.

Comment: Since most people only one one alignment column, align is faster to type, and does not require you to specify an argument to the env

Answer (score 2):

You have another possibility with the `mathtools` package: it defines an `\ArrowBetweenLines` command which places by  default an `\Updownarrow` *between* the lines of an `alignat` environment, on the left. There is a starred version which places it on the right.

It accepts as an optional argument the symbol that will be used, and I took advantage of this feature to define a `\TextBetweenLines` command, that I used in the second example in the O.P.'s question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\TextBetweenLines[1]{\ArrowBetweenLines[\text{#1}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
                     & & y_{0} & =\frac{\pm\sqrt{1-z^{2}}}{z} \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines & & y_{0}z & =\pm\sqrt{1-z^{2}} \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines & & y_{0}^{2}z^{2} & =1-z^{2}
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  y_{0}^{2}z^{2} & =1-z^{2} & & \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines *(1+y_{0})z^{2} & =1 & & \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines* z & =\pm\frac{1}{1+y_{0}^{2}}. & &
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
                         & & D_{1} & \coloneqq C_{a}\cap\left\{ (x,y,z)\in D_{2}:x>0\right\} \\
  \TextBetweenLines{and} & & D_{2} & :=\left\{ (x,y,z)\in D_{1}:x<0\right\} .
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting, alternative way for typesetting, but unfortunately I can't use, as I have rather rigid guidelines to follow.