# Definitions in math formulas

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to have definitions like `$x :=1$` in my tex to look good, and to be really different from a statement of equality like `$x = 1$`.

However, the `$:$` and `$=$` are not alligned, and this looks ugly.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-typeset-correctly). The package mathtools provides 'coloneqq' (:=) and 'eqqcolon' (=:).