# How to typset $:\iff$ (logical equivalence)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, typography, mathtools

How shall I typeset ":<=>" in Latex which means ["is logical equivalent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_based_on_equality_sign)? After typing `A :\iff B` I get

[image]

Comparing it with `A \coloneqq B` (cf. [How to typeset $:=$ correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-typeset-correctly) ):

[image]

We see that there is a bigger space between the colon and the `\iff` symbol in `A :\iff B`. Unfortunately I haven't found a symbol in [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) for this purpose...

**My attempts:** The result of `A \ordinarycolon\iff B`

[image]

and `A \vcentcolon\iff B`:

[image]

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Perfect ;-) This can question can be thus marked as a duplicate...

Comment: glad to hear that. If you want to have a long version it would be `% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 \[ A \vcentcolon\Longleftrightarrow B \]
\end{document}`