# Align $:=$ with $=$ in align/split mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath, split

I am writing a sequence of inequalities in math mode, where the first line defines the first object. To be clear, I have something like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphics,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amscd, amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &:= B - C \\
&= U + V \\
&\geq Z.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like the `=` from the `:=` in the first line to be aligned with the `=` in the second line. If I use the code above, it does not happen. Similarly, if I use `\coloneqq` in place of `:=`, the same misplacement happen. On the other hand, if I write `:&=`, I get the alignment I want; yet, in this way the column gets too far from the equal sign and it renders in an unpleasant way.

How can I get the alignment I want without having `:` too far from `=`?

Comment: `&\mathrel{\phantom{:}}= U + V`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have the `=` in `:=` aligned with the `=` below ?

Comment: @Manuel But then you have to add the `\phantom` to all subsequent lines, don't you ? Maybe it is more simple to have : `A:&= B-C` and then leave all further lines unchanged ? An even better solution probably involves the [`mathtools` command `\coloneqq`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4217/116936)

Comment: @marsupilam Or define `\colonalign` and use that every instance you need. Or may be `:\joinrel\joinrel&=` works if you put it just in the first line? (Can't test right now.)

Comment: @marsupilam Yes, I mean that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphics,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amscd, amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A :={}& B - C \\
={}& U + V \\
\geq{}& Z.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With a TABstack, one does not need to add the blank groups that the `split` version needs, because TABstacks automatically, by default, add a group to the right end of each cell.  The blank group can be defaulted to the left of each cell with the declaration `\TABbinaryLeft` (also `\TABunaryRight`), or blank groups can be added to both ends of each cell with `\TABbinary`.  The original default condition can be restored with `\TABbinaryRight` (also `\TABunaryLeft`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphics,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amscd, amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
A \coloneqq& B - C \\
=& U + V \\
\geq& Z.
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I preferably use `\coloneqq` instead of `:=`, since `\coloneqq` comes ready made with vertical symmetry, whereas `:=` does not.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This produces perfect alignment, and only affects the first line.

as shown by replacing the first `\\` by `\\[-.9\baselineskip]`.

However, it might be a bit silly...

### The output

#### with `\\[-.9\baselineskip]`

[image]

#### without

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength\myUselessLength
\begin{document}
\settowidth{\myUselessLength}{${}={}$}
$
\begin{aligned}
  A\coloneqq{}\hspace{-\myUselessLength} & \phantom{{}={}} B - C \\
                                         & = U + V               \\
                                         & \geq Z.               \\
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If someone knows how **not** to have to use a useless length for doing such a thing, I'm all ears !

Answer (score 2):

Another way, same output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    & \phantom{{}={}} \mathllap{A\coloneqq{}} B - C \\
    & = U + V                                       \\
    & \geq Z.                                       \\
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```