# What is the purpose of : in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

What is the purpose of `$:$`?

We know that in math mode one should write in natural language and not being so strict with math notation.

For example: `$f:A\to B$` is not "correct", the correct way would be `$f\colon A\to B$` (and variants).

I do not remember any math book that uses the colon as part of a sentence in math mode.

The only 2 uses I can give to `$:$` are when learning about divisions (`$2:4=1:2$`) and scales (`$1:2$`).

Does (La)TeX give a meaning of `:` in math mode?

Comment: The colon is not used for division in USA/British tradition. In scale ratios, I'd prefer spacing the colon as a relation rather than an operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `:` is a relational symbol in TeX.  In the TeXbook it is used in conjunction with `=`.

```
Plain \TeX\ treats the four characters |=|, |<|, |>|, and |:|\ as
``^{relations}'' because they express a relationship between two
quantities. For example, `${x<y}$' means that $x$~is less than~$y$.
Such relationships have a rather different meaning from binary
operations like $+$, and the symbols are typeset somewhat differently:
\beginmathdemo
|$x=y>z$|&x=y>z\cr
|$x:=y$|&x:=y\cr
|$x\le y\ne z$|&x\le y\ne z\cr
|$x\sim y\simeq z$|&x\sim y\simeq z\cr
|$x\equiv y\not\equiv z$|&x\equiv y\not\equiv z\cr
|$x\subset y\subseteq z$|&x\subset y\subseteq z\cr
\endmathdemo
```

In the comments, egreg pointed out another example in the TeXbook, where `:` is used to separate the condition from the set variable.

```
\beginmathdemo
|$\{\,x\mid x>5\,\}$|&\{\,x\mid x>5\,\}\cr
|$\{\,x:x>5\,\}$|&\{\,x:x>5\,\}\cr
\endmathdemo
(Some authors prefer to use a ^{colon} instead of `$\mid$', as in the second
example here.)
```

The colon has the exact same meaning in Plain TeX and LaTeX, as can be verified using this simple document:

```
\showthe\mathcode`:
\csname @@end\endcsname
\bye
```

The output is

```
$ pdftex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
> 12346.
l.1 \showthe\mathcode`:

? 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
> 12346.
l.1 \showthe\mathcode`:

? 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

---

Here the same table rendered in LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\lstMakeShortInline|
\begin{tabular}{l>{$}l<{$}}
|$x=y>z$|                 & x=y>z                 \\
|$x:=y$|                  & x:=y                  \\
|$x\le y\ne z$|           & x\le y\ne z           \\
|$x\sim y\simeq z$|       & x\sim y\simeq z       \\
|$x\equiv y\not\equiv z$| & x\equiv y\not\equiv z \\
|$x\subset y\subseteq z$| & x\subset y\subseteq z \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think := should be typeset with `\coloneqq`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4217/156344. One should not use `$a:=b$` as Knuth said.

Comment: The claim that `:` "is intended to be used in conjunction with =" seems a bit too strong. E.g., it seems perfectly ok to use `:` to denote conditioning on an event. (See my answer for a specific example.)

Comment: If you inspect the typeset version of `:=` closely, you'll notice that the colon symbol is centered vertically on the equals symbol. Not good, at least not for math-typesetting gourmets. That's why it's useful to write `\coloneq`, `\coloneqq`, etc.

Comment: @JouleV That is an entirely different question than the one asked by OP.

Comment: @Mico If you use a good typesetting system like ConTeXt, it will automatically “ligature” `:=` into `≔`.

Comment: @Mico If you look in the Metafontbook, you will see “:=” clearly input as `:=`. Whether the `mathtools` macros `\coloneqq` should be used is a question of personal choice and taste (I would never use `:=` in my math, of course). I agree that `:=` is by no means “the” intended usage (see page 174 in the TeXbook for the main one). In proportions such as `a:b=c:d` I'd not treat the colon as a binary operation.

Comment: @egreg I hold against your claim that `:=` is not the intended usage by pointing out exercise 18.9.

Comment: @HenriMenke It is not *“the”* (in the sense of the unique) intended usage.

Comment: @JouleV -- While `\coloneqq` exists now (and should now be used), it did *not* exist when TeX was created -- there simply wasn't enough memory to accommodate all possible symbols.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes. So what I mean is that, `:` _was_ meaningful, but _is_ meaningless.

Comment: @egreg For `:=` I use always your `\mathrel{\mathop:}=` :-) from Comprensive list symbols.

Comment: @Sebastiano good to know!

Comment: @HenriMenke you have provided an answer regarding TeX. What about LaTeX? Thanks.

Comment: @manooooh The colon has the exact same meaning in TeX and LaTeX.  I added a simple document to verify this to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Quite often, one sees `:` employed in place of a vertical bar (`|`) to denote conditioning on some event or condition. E.g., both `$E(X : X>0)$` and `$E(X\mid X>0)$` would express the "expectation of the random variable `X` conditional on this random variable taking on positive values".

By default, TeX treats both `:` and `\mid` -- but not `|` and `\vert` -- as "relational" operators and inserts an amount of whitespace around them that's also used for other relational operators such as `<`, `=`, and `>`.

For other, i.e., non-conditioning math uses of the colon symbol, one should employ `\colon`, `\coloneq` (or, depending on the package that's in use, `\coloneqq`, etc.