# Error in LaTeX code for a Matrix

Tags: errors, matrices

Can someone please find out what's the error in this code?

```
\begin{equation}
W(f_1,\dots,f_g):= \text{det} \begin{pmatrix}
                            f_1 & f_2 & \dots & f_g\\
                            f_1^' & f_2^' & \dots & f_g^'\\
                            . & . & &.\\
                            . & . & &.\\
                            . & . & &.\\
                            f_1^{(g-1)} & f_2^{(g-1)}& \dots & f_g^{(g-1)}
                            \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Use `f_1^{\prime}` instead of `f_1^'`.

Comment: Also `\det` instead of `\text{det}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
W(f_1,\dotsc,f_g) := \text{det} 
    \begin{pmatrix}
f_1         & f_2           & \dots & f_g           \\
f_1'        & f_2'          & \dots & f_g'          \\ % <---
.           & .             &       & .             \\
.           & .             &       & .             \\
.           & .             &       & .             \\
f_1^{(g-1)} & f_2^{(g-1)}   & \dots & f_g^{(g-1)}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
or better
\begin{equation}
W(f_1,\dotsc,f_g) := \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
f_1         & f_2           & \dots     & f_g           \\
f_1'        & f_2'          & \dots     & f_g'          \\
\vdots      & \vdots        & \ddots    & \vdots        \\
f_1^{(g-1)} & f_2^{(g-1)}   & \dots     & f_g^{(g-1)}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
To some people prefer to use instead `:=` different symbols for definition. Discussion and different symbols about this symbols you can find in [How to typeset := correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-typeset-correctly). For example `\coloneqq` from the package `mathtools` or `\colonequals` from the package `colonequals`, etc. Differences between are subtle, however for people with with a keen sense of aesthetics they are important. For comparison observe the case of use of `\colonequals`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
W(f_1,\dotsc,f_g) \coloneqq \det\begin{pmatrix}
        f_1         & f_2           & \dots     & f_g           \\
        f_1'        & f_2'          & \dots     & f_g'          \\
        \vdots      & \vdots        & \ddots    & \vdots        \\
        f_1^{(g-1)} & f_2^{(g-1)}   & \dots     & f_g^{(g-1)}
                                \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further possibility is use the `unicode-math` with `xelatex˙or`lualatex`engine. This fonts define`\coloneq` which gives:

[image]

@Sebastiano, thank you for pointing me on this detail. Personally I very rare if ever use (due to my professional background) symbols for *equal by definition* :-)

Comment: I prefer, using `\usepackage{mathtools}` the symbol $\coloneqq$ instead of classic :=....but there is my upvote for all users.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much. I was in dilemma, use "classic `:=` or use `\coloneqq` from `mathtools`. On the end I decide to stick with `classic". Personal I very rare if ever use symbols for definition.

Comment: Very Kind Zarko use instead the classic macro of egreg :-) `\mathrel{\mathop:}=`.

Comment: @Sebastiano, please see addendum in my answer :-)

Comment: I've been joking a lot, I hope you know about this. :):):):). I hope that I can afford to joke with you too.

Comment: @Sebastiano, of course you can, actually joking are welcome! To be only serious is so boring :-(

Answer (score 4):

Use `f_1^{\prime}` instead of `f_1^'`.

[image]

I suggest to use `\ddots` and `\vdots`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
W(f_1,\dots,f_g):= \det
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    f_1         & f_2           & \dots & f_g \\
                    f_1^{\prime}& f_2^{\prime}  & \dots & f_g^{\prime} \\
                    \vdots      & \vdots        & \ddots& \vdots \\
                    f_1^{(g-1)} & f_2^{(g-1)}   & \dots & f_g^{(g-1)}
                \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```