# Mathtools and PGFPlots conflict: `centercolon` and `addlegendentry` do not compile

Tags: pgfplots, mathtools, legend

I am using `\mathtoolsset{centercolon}` in a document, together with PGFPlots. I noticed that if I insert a colon in the `\addlegendentry` command, the document keeps compiling forever and never produces any output.

This also occurs when using the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4218/26355), so, taking inspiration from that, I could fix it up using `\ordinarycolon`. However, it's not clear to me **why this is happening** within `\addlegendsentry`, and especially I was wondering if **it's possible to fix it in a way that I do not need special treatment** for legends in order to compile.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Does not compile when this is on:
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot {-5*x^3 - x^2};
      % Needs extra braces somehow, but does not compile
      \addlegendentry{{$f(x) : A\to B$}}
      % Took inspiration from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4218/26355,
      % using \ordinarycolon this compiles:
      % \addlegendentry{{$f(x) \ordinarycolon A\to B$}}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, centercolon make the : active which tikz/pgf properly doesn't like as : is used as a part of the tikz/pgf syntax. Not sure if loading the babel tikz library might help. Why do you use centercolon in the first place?

Comment: I noticed it had problem parsing the legend as well if I didn't add braces around it, but I am surprised it expands into the formula instead of transferring it to the legend node?
I use `centercolon` to get nicely aligned `:=` in the document where I took the MVE from.

Comment: You should be using `\coloneq`, then there's no active colons